# What are the plugged pipes on the outside of my roof staircase wall?

Tags: water, roof

There are also these pipes sticking out from the wall of my rental home. I guess they are either gas, water, or disconnected. Are they a common thing? Like for a sink?

The owner is coming later this week to check for a water leak. I need to know if he is going to scour the room near where these pipes are because it’s at least a day of cleaning if true.

[image]

Comment: You seem to be asking, in a roundabout way, whether there could be water in those pipes. The only answer we can possibly provide is "maybe". My wild guess is that they're air conditioner refrigerant lines, since there's apparently no drain, but who knows? We don't have enough information to go further.

Answer (score 2):

yes, that's odd.

However, while they are copper pipe usually used for water lines, their location (outside, 'roof' area, stairway on other side indicating no ability to place a water related item there) suggest to me that they have another purpose.

I believe that these were **ad-hock brackets to provide attachment and support of some object. My first guess would be a satellite dish.**

No matter the old purpose, they do need to be water tight. However, that is an issue for your landlord and I don't think that you have any worries.

Comment: Satellite dish is an interesting possibility, because then the pipe could be both a physical support *and* used as a conduit for the wiring. I'm pretty sure that conduit for 120V/240V wiring is not allowed to be used as a support, but if it is low voltage then that's not an issue.

Comment: Another thought, perhaps to an old solar water heater with a homeowner installation (less than professional)

Answer (score 2):

There's a huge difference in my head between "plugged up" and "capped". "Plugged up" means unintentionally clogged with debris, bird's nests, etc., while "capped" means someone went to the effort to put the appropriate (or at least *a*) cap on the pipe. These do appear to be "capped" which means someone was intentional about it.

Is it "common"? Yes, when you have a pipe of some sort that leads through an exterior wall, but it's no longer needed, it's more likely to be capped than removed. Is it "common" that pipes that penetrate to the exterior of a building are no longer needed? Eh, not as much.

Removal requires access to the inside of the wall which requires tearing up the wall on the inside or outside, then repairing the wall. It involves, at a minimum, repairing the hole in the exterior wall to make it water/bug/wind/weather proof. Since that has already been done (theoretically) with the pipe in place, it's much simpler to simply cap off the pipe and not bother with all the extra work.

Also, since we have no idea where the water leak is, there is no way we would have a clue if the landlord is going to need access to the other side of this wall. If *you* know the leak is somewhere near there, then it's probably pretty safe to assume he will need to get to that wall and you'd best start cleaning. If the leak's on the other side of the house, then this area probably doesn't have anything to do with it.

In either case, a little bit of cleaning up doesn't seem to be a bad thing.